# Закрытие предыдущего окна при открытии нового

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Во время написания кода на Tkinter с помощью ЯП python версии 3.8.0 встретился с проблемой: не закрывается предыдущее окно программы. То есть при нажатии на кнопки предыдущее окно должно закрываться и открываться новое, но нигде не могу найти решение этой проблемы.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Код прилагается:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Электронный формуляр")
        self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        #Кнопка "Ученик"
        self.button = tk.Button(self,text="Ученик", command=lambda: SW())
        self.button.place(x=100,y=150)
        #Кнопка "Учитель"
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self,text="Учитель", command=lambda: TW())
        self.button1.place(x=100,y=200)
        #Кнопка "Другой посетитель"
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self,text="Другой посетитель", command=lambda: FW())
        self.button2.place(x=100,y=250)
        #Кнопка "Добавить книги в ЧБ"
        self.btn_add=tk.Button(self, text='Добавить книги в ЧБ',command=lambda: Main())
        self.btn_add.place(x=56, y=70)
        #Кнопка "Просмотреть ЧБ"
        self.btn_watch=tk.Button(self, text='Просмотреть ЧБ',command=lambda: Watch())
        self.btn_watch.place(x=185, y=70)
        #Кнопка "Уведомления"
        self.btn_notif=tk.Button(self, text='Уведомления',command=lambda: Not())
        self.btn_notif.place(x=291, y=70)




class SW(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Ученик")
        self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        #кнопка "Добавить книги в ЧБ"
        self.btn_add=tk.Button(self, text='Добавить книги в ЧБ', command=lambda: Main())
        self.btn_add.place(x=56, y=70)

        #кнопка "Посмотреть ЧБ"
        self.btn_watch=tk.Button(self, text='Просмотреть ЧБ',command=lambda: Watch())
        self.btn_watch.place(x=185, y=70)

        #кнопка "Уведомления"
        self.btn_notif=tk.Button(self, text='Уведомления',command=lambda: Not())
        self.btn_notif.place(x=291, y=70)

        #кнопка "Сохранить"
        self.btn_save=tk.Button(self, text='Сохранить')
        self.btn_save.place(x=800, y=415)

        #место ввода "ФИО"
        self.en_fio=tk.Entry(self,width=25)
        self.en_fio.place_configure(x=56, y=140)

        #место ввода "Класс"
        self.en_class=tk.Entry(self,width=3)
        self.en_class.place_configure(x=257, y=140)

        #место ввода "Литера"
        self.en_lit=tk.Entry(self,width=3)
        self.en_lit.place_configure(x=355, y=140)

        #надпись "ФИО"
        self.lb_fio=tk.Label(text='ФИО')
        self.lb_fio.place(x=26,y=140)

        #надпись "Класс"
        self.lb_class=tk.Label(text='Класс')
        self.lb_class.place(x=220,y=140)

        #надпись "Литера"
        self.lb_lit=tk.Label(text='Литера')
        self.lb_lit.place(x=310,y=140)




class TW(SW): 

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.title("Учитель")
        self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
        #кнопка "Добавить книги в ЧБ"
        self.btn_add=tk.Button(self, text='Добавить книги в ЧБ', command=lambda: Main())
        self.btn_add.place(x=56, y=70)

        #кнопка "Посмотреть ЧБ"
        self.btn_watch=tk.Button(self, text='Просмотреть ЧБ',command=lambda: Watch())
        self.btn_watch.place(x=185, y=70)

        #кнопка "Уведомления"
        self.btn_notif=tk.Button(self, text='Уведомления',command=lambda: Not())
        self.btn_notif.place(x=291, y=70)

        #кнопка "Сохранить"
        self.btn_save=tk.Button(self, text='Сохранить')
        self.btn_save.place(x=800, y=415)

        #надпись "ФИО"
        self.lb_fio=tk.Label(text='ФИО')
        self.lb_fio.place(x=26,y=140)


        #место ввода "ФИО"
        self.en_fio=tk.Entry(self,width=25)
        self.en_fio.place_configure(x=56, y=140)





class FW(tk.Toplevel):
      def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
          tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
          self.title("Другой посетитель")
          self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
          self.resizable(False, False)

          #кнопка "Добавить книги в ЧБ"
          self.btn_add=tk.Button(self, text='Добавить книги в ЧБ', command=lambda: Main())
          self.btn_add.place(x=56, y=70)

          #кнопка "Посмотреть ЧБ"
          self.btn_watch=tk.Button(self, text='Просмотреть ЧБ',command=lambda: Watch())
          self.btn_watch.place(x=185, y=70)

          #кнопка "Уведомления"
          self.btn_notif=tk.Button(self, text='Уведомления',command=lambda: Not())
          self.btn_notif.place(x=291, y=70)

          #кнопка "Сохранить"
          self.btn_save=tk.Button(self, text='Сохранить')
          self.btn_save.place(x=800, y=415)

          #надпись "ФИО"
          self.lb_fio=tk.Label(text='ФИО')
          self.lb_fio.place(x=26,y=140)


          #место ввода "ФИО"
          self.en_fio=tk.Entry(self,width=25)
          self.en_fio.place_configure(x=56, y=140)


class Not(tk.Toplevel):
      def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
          tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
          self.title("Другой посетитель")
          self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
          self.resizable(False, False)


class Watch(tk.Toplevel):
      def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
          tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
          self.title("Другой посетитель")
          self.geometry("900x450+300+200")
          self.resizable(False, False)



if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = Main()
     app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Должно быть одно главное окно не надо чтобы из дочернего окна опять вызывалось родительское смотрите метод destroy

Comment: Проблема с невозможностью закрытия главного окна в Python в Инете обсуждается.
Мне понравился такой ответ: [![скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R2qW.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2R2qW.jpg)

Comment: А вот как можно создать это невидимое окно???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для скрытия окна (`Tk` или `Toplevel`) можно использовать метод `withdraw`:

```
def next_window():
    root.withdraw()
    second_window = tk.Toplevel()
    

bt = tk.Button(root, text="Следующее окно", command=next_window)
```

Только учитывайте, что при закрытии второго окна скрытое основное окно продолжит существовать, поэтому программа не прекратит выполнение. Нужно дополнительно обрабатывать закрытие дочерних окон, чтобы при их закрытии принудительно выполнялось закрытие главного окна программы:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def next_window():
    root.withdraw()  # Скрыть окно
    second_window = tk.Toplevel()
    # При закрытии дочернего окна убиваем главное окно:
    second_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: root.destroy())
    # или так: second_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.destroy)


bt = tk.Button(root, text="Следующее окно", command=next_window)
bt.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

По вашей программе:

- Конструкции вида `command=lambda: Main()` можно заменить на `command=Main`
- Конструкции вида `tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)` (вызов инициализации родительского класса) лучше заменить на
  `super().__init__(*args, *kwargs)`
- Классы `Not` и `Watch` полностью совпадают. В таких случаях можно не делать два отдельных класса, а просто создавать два экземпляра одного и того же класса.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, два класс Not и Watch ещё не сделанны, поэтому они пока схожи)